# c# mvc project DB data backward compability

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have encountered a problem in the project that I am developing and I would like to consult about the solution.The app must support more than one version.Versions of the web page related to the number of parameters  and the name can vary in the database.We can make the web page dynamic by using the entity framework but when the version is upgraded, the cost of making old tables compatible with new tables comes up.
How can I get rid of this cost?Can you help me?

project :c# mvc project
DB : Mssql

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known problem in environments where more than one version of the website is supported.  It is also a well known problem in the microservices world, where multiple different versions of the same microservice must be supported.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way out. You have to write the code that does the mapping of functionality between different versions, and you have to be prepared to keep writing this version mapping code forever.

That's why the concept of breaking changes vs. non-breaking changes has been invented.  When new functionality is introduced which is so different from the old functionality that we cannot really map the old to the new, we say that we have a breaking change, we increment the **major** version number, and we put the new version of code and data separately from the old, thus breaking support of the old stuff.  When the change is not breaking, then we write the mapping code and we only increment the **minor** version number, indicating that the new stuff retains backwards compatibility with the old stuff.

Some non-technical decision maker within your company may *think* that being backwards-compatible should not be a big deal, and may have promised it to customers, but he has to be informed that the sad reality is that every once in a while there will be breaking changes.